Can a function $f$ exist such that $f(x)f(y) = xy + 1$ for positive real $x$ and $y$

Problem. Can a function $f$ exist such that $f(x)f(y) = xy + 1$ for positive real $x$ and $y$

If not, is there something like a next best thing, perhaps only for integers, finite field, or maybe only for most values rather than all.
If something like this can exist it would be huge to get an explicit formula, as it would make computing something much simpler.
I sincerely apologize if this is actually trivial or if it's an ill formed question. But I honestly can't think of anything.

"computing something much simpler"  computing what?

The usual start to such a problem is to try various values, like $(x,y)=(0,0)$, to see what you can learn.

Putting $y=x$ gives $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$. But it is clear this doesn't satisfy the equation for $x \ne y$.

@WillJagy dot product between vectors in 'homogoneous coordinates' so basically 1 dimension just set to 1 ex. [x, y ,1]. It's not that the dot product is complicated, it's more that every single dimension costs A LOT thanks to some highly specific details. A function like this would allow me to transform my N D vectors to N-1 D vectors at compile time. There are too many tiny little details i would have to provide in order to give full context. So i thought it best to just omit it entirely as it would only distract from the main point.

Nope.
For $y=x$ your requirement implies $f(x)^2=x^2+1,$ so $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1},$ so $f(1)=\sqrt 2.$
But then, for $y=1$ you get $f(x)f(y) = f(x)f(1) = f(x)\cdot \sqrt 2 = \sqrt{2x^2+2}$
which contradicts your requirement, which gives $f(x)f(1)=x\cdot 1+1 = x+1.$

Aw shucks! I had the feeling it was too good to be true. Very clean and elegent proof though. I imgaine answering the 'next best thing' part is just far too difficult since we don't even know what 'next best' means. Anyways thanks a bunch!

Certainly not.  You would need $f(0)f(y)=0\cdot y + 1 =1$ for all $y$, implying that that $f(y)=\pm 1$ for all $y$.  But $f(1)^2=1\cdot 1+1=2$, a contradiction.

Nitpicking: taking things strictly, your answer reaches out of the defined domain of `positive real $x$ and $y$.  by using $x=0$. Anyway, the same argument can be made with $x$ positive close enough to $0$, so the conclusion holds.  :)

Quite right, I missed the “positive” restriction and thought the function had to be defined over $\mathbb{R}$.

You asked about finite fields, so let's see what happens if we avoid square roots: $f(x)f(0)=1$. Therefore, $f(x)=1 \cdot f(0)^{-1}$ and $f(0) \ne 0$. This means $f(x)$ is constant.
We also have $f(0)^2=1$, $f(1)^2=1+1$. Since $f(0)=f(1)$, this is only true if $1=1+1$.
Maybe on a weaker algebraic structure than a field you could make something work?

Perhaps too trivial
$f(x) f(0)=1,$
hence $f(0)\not=0;$
$f(x) =\dfrac{1}{f(0)}$, hence
$f(x) = c$, with some constant $c$ ($\not =0$);
$f(x) f(y) =c^2 \not = xy+1$

There seems to be no useful "next best thing" that is true! To see this, consider an integral domain (containing a multiplicative neutral element $ 1 $) $ R $, and assume that $ x , y , u , v \in R $ satisfy
$$ \begin {cases}
u ^ 2 = x ^ 2 + 1 \text ; \\
v ^ 2 = y ^ 2 + 1 \text ; \\
u v = x y + 1 \text .
\end {cases} $$
Then we have
$$ ( x ^ 2 + 1 ) ( y ^ 2 + 1 ) = u ^ 2 v ^ 2 = ( u v ) ^ 2 = ( x y + 1 ) ^ 2 \text , $$
which by simple algebraic manipulations implies $ ( x - y ) ^ 2 = 0 $, and therefore $ x = y $ and $ u = v $.
This means that if you want to have a function $ f : S \to R $ on a subset $ S $ of $ R $ satisfying your functional equation (your original problem was asking for $ R = \mathbb R $ and $ S = \mathbb R _ + $), then $ S $ must have at most one element (just consider $ x , y \in S $, set $ u = f ( x ) $ and $ v = f ( y ) $ and follow the above argument).
